# PHP cURL with POST and cookies failing - "cookies not enabled"

Tags: php, post, curl, cookies

I'm trying to pull through some data using the code below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ms.spreadex.com/viewservice/getview");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);

$data = array(
    'dir' => '',
    'pViewRef' => 'mnu/home/10006/ts=1421207308239.41',
    'timeStamp' => '1421251162476',
    'viewRef' => 'page//248616/'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error saying cookies are not enabled.

If I try cURLing the URL visited immediately prior to the POST request above first, I still get the same issue:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ms.spreadex.com/Main.aspx#header");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any idea of where I'm going wrong?

For clarity, the response I get using cURL is as follows:

{"Successful":true,"Html":"\u003cdiv id=\"view\" class=\"\" vref=\"help/nocookies/0/\" requires=\"\" \u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\u0027pgTitle\u0027\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\u0027block\u0027 vref=\u0027\u0027\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/div\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\u0027titleWrap\u0027\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\u0027title\u0027\u003eCookies Required\u003c/div\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\u0027subtitle \u0027\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n \u003c/div\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\u0027block\u0027 vref=\u0027\u0027\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"panels\"\u003e\r\n\t\u003cdiv class=\"panel rnd3 txtsml n\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"mrgsgl\"\u003e\r\n You have disabled cookies in your mobile browser.\r\n \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"mrgsgl\"\u003e\r\n Our mobile platform uses cookies to provide you with a great trading experience.\r\n In the Browser Settings menu on your handset, make sure that you have enabled cookies, then try again.\r\n \u003c/div\u003e\r\n \u003cdiv class=\"mrgsgl\"\u003e\r\n If you need assistance, please call our Helpdesk on \r\n \u003ca href=\"#\" to=\"+441727895000\" name=\"Helpdesk\"\u003e01727 895 000\u003c/a\u003e.\r\n \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e","Context":"","Status":"1","PendingCookies":null,"TriggerVref":"","IsLoggedIn":false,"IsExpired":false}

whereas the following is what I'd get if I posted the same data to the URL via a browser:

{"Successful":true,"Html":"\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"view\" vref=\"page/spr/248616/ts=1421212688114.75\" requires=\"\" ispush=\"1\"  \u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\u0027pgTitle mrgfix\u0027\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\u0027nav prev\u0027 vref=\u0027page/spr/248616/ts=1421212688114.75\u0027\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"titleWrap\"\u003e\r\n                \u003cdiv class=\"innerTitleWrap\"\u003e\r\n                    \u003cdiv class=\"title\"\u003e Tottenham v Burnley\u003c/div\u003e\r\n                \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\u0027nav next\u0027 vref=\u0027page/spr/248616/ts=1421212688114.75\u0027\u003e\u0026nbsp;\u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n    \r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"modelTbl pricing-page\" dref=\"PgSprtXXItm_248616\" ispush=\"1\" eventtypename=\"Football\"\u003e            \r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"tblbody\"\u003e\r\n                    \u003cspan class=\"page-subtitle\" class=\"push\" code=\"DE\"\u003e\r\n                        Wednesday, 20:00\r\n                    \u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"tab-buttons \"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"nav tab spreads  sel\" vref=\"page/spr/248616\"\u003eSpread Betting\u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"nav tab fixedOdds \" vref=\"page/fo/248616\" status=\"1\"\u003eFixed Odds\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\r\n       \r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXGrp_753383\" \r\n     class=\"panel dref expanded Spreads TwoPerRowTopToBottom\" \r\n     dref=\"TraSprtSprXGrp_753383\" \r\n     ispush=\"1\"\r\n     showsuspended=\"1\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"title-bar\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"minmax max\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"h1\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"GN\"\u003ePopular Markets\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"content\"\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642868\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642868\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642868/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eTottenham/Burnley\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e1.1\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e1.3\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e0-0\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642869\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642869\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642869/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eTotal Goals\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e2.9\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e3.1\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e0\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642872\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642872\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642872/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003e1st Match Goal\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e31\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e34\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642873\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642873\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642873/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003e1st Spurs Goal\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e40\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e43\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642874\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642874\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642874/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003e1st Burnley Goal\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e61\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e64\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642882\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642882\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642882/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eTotal Goal Minutes\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e149\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e159\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e0\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642899\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642899\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642899/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eTottenham to win match\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e61.9\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e68\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642900\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642900\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642900/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eMatch to be drawn\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e19\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e23.1\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642901\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642901\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642901/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eBurnley to win match\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e11.1\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e15.4\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv id=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642903\" \r\n    class=\"item iconRow comp dref\" \r\n        status=\"L\" dref=\"TraSprtSprXMkt_10642903\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"iconRowL info\"\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"inner iconRowR row nav chevron\" vref=\"bet/spr/10642903/\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"N\"\u003eOver/Under 2.5 Goals\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv class=\"row\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv id=\"selLive\" class=\"pnlL \"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003ePrice:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"B\"\u003e54.5\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan\u003e-\u003c/span\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"A\"\u003e62\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"pnlR hide\"\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"n\"\u003eSo Far:\u003c/label\u003e\r\n                \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"SF\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"selNotLive\" class=\"gray b hide\"\u003eSelection Not Live\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cspan id=\"mktClosed\" class=\"gray b marketClosed hide\"\u003e\r\n            Market Closed\r\n        \u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003cdiv id=\"selSettled\" class=\"gray row hide\"\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"gray\"\u003eSettled @\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"M\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"panel-info no-border\"\u003e\r\n            \r\n            \u003cdiv class=\"eachWay\" style=\u0027display:none\u0027\u003e\r\n                \u003clabel class=\"b\"\u003eEach way: \u003c/label\u003e\r\n                1/\u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"WR\"\u003e0\u003c/span\u003e odds first  \u003cspan class=\"push\" code=\"WP\"\u003e0\u003c/span\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"bottom\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003c/div\u003e\r\n        \u003cscript\u003e\r\n            pricingPageHelper.loadRestOfPanels(\u0027page/spr/248616/ts=1421212688114.75\u0027);\r\n            \r\n        \u003c/script\u003e\r\n\r\n\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n","Context":"","Status":"1","PendingCookies":null,"TriggerVref":"","IsLoggedIn":false,"IsExpired":false}

Comment: When you say "it throws an error saying cookies are not enabled", what is "it"? Can you show the specific message in your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I'm literally echoing the output of cURL, and this returns the following from cURL:

Comment: Sorry - posting back above because it's too long!

Comment: Try creating a blank cookies.txt in the same directory

Comment: chmod on your cookies.txt must be 0666

Comment: you can also try setting the cookies manually which are set by browser javascript instead of server side script. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "fruit=apple; colour=red");